# Display only found results

Tags: java, arrays

A follow up to my Item Scanner, a java tool that scans through a directory of *.txt files.

Thank you all for the help! However now I have a different problem.

When I get the results it reads strings I do not want it to read.  How can I block out these strings I do not want it reading?

This is an example what I mean:

```
Enter item to find: 1112
Found   125000000

[BANK]

[FRIENDS]

[IGNORES]

[EOF]

 time(s) in kyle.txt!
Found   1000000

[FRIENDS]

[IGNORES]

[EOF]

 time(s) in kylea.txt!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I want it to display the results like this:

```
Enter item to find: 1112
Found 125000000 time(s) in kyle.txt!
Found 1000000 time(s) in kylea.txt!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

How would I do this? I tried creating an array list to block the other results I do not need, but I can't get it to work either.

Thank you for the help!

Also, here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ItemScanner {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.print("Enter item to find: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    find(sc.nextLine());
}

public static void find(String delim) {
    File dir = new File("accounts");
    if (dir.exists()) {
        String read;
        try {
            File files[] = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File loaded = files[i];
                if (loaded.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loaded));
                    StringBuffer load = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        load.append(read + "\n");
                    }
                    String delimiter[] = new String(load).split(delim);

                    if(delimiter.length > 1) {
                    System.out.println("Found " + (delimiter[1]) + " time(s) in " +       loaded.getName() + "!");
                    }
                }
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("error: dir wasn't found!");
    }
}
}
```

Also, an example of an account it scans through, here is an account:

```
[ACCOUNT]
character-username = kylea
character-password = 

[CHARACTER]
character-height = 0
character-isactive = 1
character-messages = 0
character-lastconnection = 
character-lastlogin = 2009/11/27
character-energy = 100

[EQUIPMENT]
character-equip = 0     4724    0   
character-equip = 1     1052    0   
character-equip = 2     6585    0   
character-equip = 3     4151    0   
character-equip = 4     4720    0   
character-equip = 5     1215    0   
character-equip = 6     -1  0   
character-equip = 7     4722    0   
character-equip = 8     -1  0   
character-equip = 9     775 0   
character-equip = 10    1837    0   
character-equip = 11    -1  0   
character-equip = 12    6735    0   
character-equip = 13    -1  0   

[LOOK]
character-look = 0      1

[SKILLS]
character-skill = 0     18  445633
character-skill = 1     15  440000
character-skill = 2     15  440000
character-skill = 3     199 1402300000
character-skill = 4     22  0
character-skill = 5     1   0
character-skill = 6     1   0
character-skill = 7     1   0
character-skill = 8     1   0
character-skill = 9     1   0
character-skill = 10    1   0
character-skill = 11    1   0
character-skill = 12    1   0
character-skill = 13    1   0
character-skill = 14    1   0
character-skill = 15    1   0
character-skill = 16    1   0
character-skill = 17    1   0
character-skill = 18    1   0
character-skill = 19    1   0
character-skill = 20    1   0
character-skill = 21    1   0
character-skill = 22    1   0
character-skill = 23    1   0
character-skill = 24    1   0

[ITEMS]
character-item = 0      6570    11
character-item = 1      666570  0525
character-item = 2      1165701 55
character-item = 3      55  66
character-item = 4      963 51
character-item = 5      961 55

[BANK]
character-bank = 0      996 1000000

[FRIENDS]

[IGNORES]

[EOF]
```

Comment: We'll probably need to see your code to give specific help like this. Can you paste some?

Comment: Why is your item to find spelled "delim"?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in this code is reading the contents of .txt files in a string buffer and splitting that file contents on a delimeter, in your example "1112" and printing the remainder of that file.

so if your file contains "aaaa11121112uh oh" it would print "1112uh oh" ? It is not clear to me what you try to accomplish.

A quick fix to only showing the number would be to use:

```
Long.valueOf(delimiter[1])
```

to parse only the number part of the remainder and print that. I have the feeling that this would not solve the underlying problem, so maybe you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here?

**Edit**
After you updated your question with an example of a data file, (which looks very much like an .ini file :-)) I think you would do good by reading through the javadoc for [Properties class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), in particular the [load()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [store()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) methods, storing your character data in a `Properties` collection.

Comment: I'm trying to search in my accounts folder to find out how much of that "item" a player has.

So in short I'm trying to read the quantity value for the item searched.

The setup is, item<TAB>quantity , so if I search for 6570 and it is found in an account, I want it to <TAB> over, and return the value of quantity.

Found 2 time(s) in Kyle.txt!


It sounds so simple but it's hard. =|

Comment: character-item<space>=<space>0<tab>6570<tab>quantity

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have mixed up some example code.  You seem from the question and main() to be looking for a particular item, but in the code, you're using the passed-in argument as a delimiter to split the line you read, and counting the number of words.

To do what your question asks, you'd need logic in which you split the read-in line, then iterate through it, comparing against the item to find.